Expandable Floating Action Button in Bottom Navigation Bar
I am trying to implement the design below

I also had the expandable fab, but when i added to AnimatedBottomNavigationBar as Notched item i have this look below

Expandable button is working but in the look there is this shadow like look which i couldn't understand. If i add a regular FloatingActionButton i had the look that i want, but there is no expandable option for the FAB.
Here is the scaffold:
class ScaffoldWithNavbar extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScaffoldWithNavbar({
    super.key,
    required this.navigationShell,
  });

  final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        backgroundColor: ColorName.appBackgroundColor,
        body: navigationShell,
        drawer: const AppDrawer(),

        floatingActionButton: ExpandableFab(
          distance: 90,
          children: [
            ActionButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.format_size),
            ),
            ActionButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.insert_photo),
            ),
            ActionButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.videocam),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        bottomNavigationBar: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
            notchSmoothness: NotchSmoothness.verySmoothEdge,
            leftCornerRadius: 25,
            rightCornerRadius: 25,
            height: 60,
            gapLocation: GapLocation.center,
            icons: const [
              Icons.home,
              Icons.ac_unit_sharp,
              Icons.access_alarm,
              Icons.abc_rounded,
            ],
            activeIndex: navigationShell.currentIndex,
            onTap: (indexPosition) {
              if (indexPosition != 3) {
                navigationShell.goBranch(
                  indexPosition,
                  initialLocation:
                      indexPosition == navigationShell.currentIndex,
                );
              } else {
                Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
              }
            },
          );
        }),
}

This is the ExpandableFab
    class ExpandableFab extends StatefulWidget {
      const ExpandableFab({
        this.initialOpen,
        required this.distance,
        required this.children,
        super.key,
      });
    
      final bool? initialOpen;
      final double distance;
      final List<Widget> children;
    
      @override
      State<ExpandableFab> createState() => _ExpandableFabState();
    }
    
    class _ExpandableFabState extends State<ExpandableFab>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      final ValueNotifier<bool> _open = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);
    
      late final AnimationController _controller;
      late final Animation<double> _expandAnimation;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _open.value = widget.initialOpen ?? false;
        _controller = AnimationController(
          vsync: this,
          value: _open.value ? 1.0 : 0.0,
          duration: const Duration(
            milliseconds: 250,
          ),
        );
        _expandAnimation = CurvedAnimation(
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          reverseCurve: Curves.easeOutQuad,
          parent: _controller,
        );
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      void _toggle() {
        _open.value = !_open.value;
        if (_open.value) {
          _controller.forward();
        } else {
          _controller.reverse();
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SizedBox.expand(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 56.w,
                height: 56.h,
                child: Center(
                  child: Material(
                    type: MaterialType.transparency,
                    shape: const CircleBorder(),
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    elevation: 4,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: _toggle,
                      child: const Padding(
                        padding: AppPadding.allWithValue(8),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          color: ColorName.primaryBlue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ..._buildExpandingActionButtons(),
              ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: _open,
                builder: (context, open, child) => IgnorePointer(
                  ignoring: open,
                  child: AnimatedContainer(
                    transformAlignment: Alignment.center,
                    transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(
                      open ? 0.7 : 1.0,
                      open ? 0.7 : 1.0,
                      1.0,
                    ),
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                    curve: const Interval(0.0, 0.5, curve: Curves.easeOut),
                    child: AnimatedOpacity(
                      opacity: open ? 0.0 : 1.0,
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                      curve: const Interval(
                        0.25,
                        1.0,
                        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: AppPadding.allRegular().copyWith(
                            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom + 16),
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                          ),
                          onPressed: _toggle,
                          child: Assets.images.fabButton.svg(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      List<Widget> _buildExpandingActionButtons() {
        final children = <Widget>[];
        final count = widget.children.length;
        final step = 180.0 / (count - 1);
        for (var i = 0, angleInDegrees = 0.0;
            i < count;
            i++, angleInDegrees += step) {
          children.add(
            ExpandingActionButton(
              directionInDegrees: angleInDegrees,
              maxDistance: widget.distance,
              progress: _expandAnimation,
              child: widget.children[i],
            ),
          );
        }
        return children;
      }
    }

And this is the ActionButton:

class ActionButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ActionButton({
    super.key,
    this.onPressed,
    required this.icon,
  });

  final VoidCallback? onPressed;
  final Widget icon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Material(
      shape: const CircleBorder(),
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      color: theme.colorScheme.secondary,
      elevation: 4,
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        icon: icon,
        color: theme.colorScheme.onSecondary,
      ),
    );
  }
}

Tried almost everything, but couldn't find the solution.

maybe this package will help yoU https://pub.dev/packages/navbar_router

I think floating_bottom_bar package will help you.

@NipulRathod that package seems to be working but it doesn't let me to do effect i added in the question. It creates quick action menu only vertically.
